# Biblatex - Modify Nature citation style

Tags: biblatex

I am currently using the Nature citation style in my document which works very well for me for all but one point. I would like to change it so that it displays the title of chapters of books and the access date of website which it currently doesn't do. How would I be able to achieve that?

Here is an MWE of what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=nature,sorting=none,backend=biber,isbn=false,date=year,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Constable2009,
abstract = {This chapter contains sections titled: * General considerations for process metrics * Materials * Equipment and operability intertwined * EHS hazards and risk * Quality * Conclusions * References},
address = {Chichester, UK},
author = {Constable, David J C and Jimenez-Gonzalez, Conchita and Lapkin, Alexei},
booktitle = {Green Chemistry Metrics},
doi = {10.1002/9781444305432.ch6},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/pmj27/Mendeley/Library/Constable, Jimenez-Gonzalez, Lapkin - 2009 - Process Metrics.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {9781405159685},
keywords = {Environmental,Equipment and operability,Hazard scoring for process materials,Petrochemical and bulk commodity chemical manufact,Process metrics,Process metrics - one size does not fit all,Process recycle - in-process and post-processing r,Specific metrics for mass,Total cost assessment or environmental accounting,health and safety hazards (EHS) risks associated w,sustainability screening},
mendeley-tags = {sustainability screening},
pages = {228--247},
publisher = {John Wiley {\&} Sons, Ltd},
title = {{Process Metrics}},
url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/9781444305432.ch6},
year = {2009}
}
@online{MetOffice2014m,
author = {{Met Office}},
title = {{Middlesbrough climate}},
url = {http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/climate/gcxn7yvv5},
urldate = {2015-11-29},
year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{Constable2009} \cite{MetOffice2014m}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your MWE does both things you are asking for. What's really missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, my MWE used `numeric-comp`. I have fixed that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `intitle` allows you to display chapter titles for `@inbook` and `@incollection` entries (i.e. their `title`s), so load the package with

```
intitle = true,
```

You already get to see the access date, but because the package sets `urldate = year,` we only get to see the year of the access date, with

```
urldate = short,
```

we get the entire date.

If you want to the see the 'visited on' string as well, you will need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```